# Why MMA cannot get the closed-form of this infinite series of B when it known that of A+B and A?

Tags: special-functions, summation

The following input

```
s1 = Sum[(2 l + 1)*t^l*LegendreP[l, Cos[θ]], {l, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {t < 1, 0 < θ < π}]
```

returns the closed-form expression $\frac{1-t^2}{\left(t^2-2 t \cos (\theta )+1\right)^{3/2}}$.

```
s2 = Sum[t^l*LegendreP[l, Cos[θ]], {l, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {t < 1, 0 < θ < π}]
```

returns $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t^2-2 t \cos (\theta )+1}}$.

But Mathematica returns the following unevaluated:

```
Sum[l*t^l*LegendreP[l, Cos[θ]], {l, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {t < 1, 0 < θ < π}]
```

The answer should be `(s1 - s2)/2`.

Why can't Mathematica compute this series?

Comment: Why can't it do `s1` in the form `Sum[(2 l + 1)*t^l*LegendreP[l, x], {l, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> {t < 1, -1 < x < 1}]`? Oh, the vagaries of symbolic algorithms!

Comment: From [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01535777), we know $s1$ is a special case of Eq. 21 of this paper, and $s2$ a generating function for Legendre Polynomials (see Eq. 2 of [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) and Eq. 1 of [this link](http://web.uconn.edu/~ch351vc/Leg3/node1.html)). And both $s1$ and $s2$  is correct.